# How do I use `lsh` as client for an OpenSSHD server with no password?

Tags: ssh

I want to try `lsh` but it seems awfully hard to getting it to talk to my OpenSSHD server. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you are ready for trying an alternative to OpenSSH's client?

Good for you. `lsh` www.gnu.org/s/lsh/ is a GNU alternative that can
work with OpenSSH's server. Unfortunately *that* is not easy.

We assume that you can `ssh` to localhost which runs OpenSSHD. Your first try is:

```
$ lsh localhost
No seed file. Please create one by running
lsh-make-seed -o "/home/tange/.lsh/yarrow-seed-file".
lsh: No randomness generator available.
```

So let us make that file:

```
$ mkdir .lsh
$ lsh-make-seed -o "/home/tange/.lsh/yarrow-seed-file"
lsh-make-seed: Reading system state...
lsh-make-seed: Got 150 bits of entropy from system state.
lsh-make-seed: Please type some random data. You better do this
lsh-make-seed: when connected directly to a console, typing over
lsh-make-seed: the network provides worse timing information, and
lsh-make-seed: more opportunities for eavesdropping.
----------------------------------------
........................................
lsh-make-seed: Got 182 keystrokes, estimating 200 bits of entropy.
lsh-make-seed: You can stop typing now.
```

Now it seems pretty stupid to me that `lsh` does not use
`/dev/urandom` and only reverts to typing on systems that do not have
this.

```
$ lsh localhost
lsh: Failed to open `/home/tange/.lsh/host-acls' for reading (errno = 2): No such file or directory
lsh: Protocol error: Algorithm negotiation failed.
```

This is due to `lsh` choosing an incompatible cipher when used with a recent OpenSSHD. Use `-c aes256-ctr` - I do not know why it does not do this automatically:

```
$ lsh -c aes256-ctr localhost
lsh: Failed to open `/home/tange/.lsh/host-acls' for reading (errno = 2): No such file or directory
lsh: Server's hostkey is not trusted. Disconnecting.
lsh: Protocol error: Bad server host key
```

Better, but not good enough. By making `lsh` less paranoid, you can get in:

```
$ lsh -c aes256-ctr --sloppy-host-authentication localhost
lsh: Failed to open `/home/tange/.lsh/host-acls' for reading (errno = 2): No such file or directory
Received unauthenticated key for host localhost
Key details:
Bubble Babble: xitem-suten-vedyd-hibuv-naril-nisog-luvet-dagik-negem-kykeb-bexyx
Fingerprint:   4b:9f:4b:4d:10:6b:09:2b:be:ee:df:48:a0:75:d3:9a
Do you trust this key? (y/n) y
Last login: Mon Dec  7 08:11:58 2015 from 192.168.1.103
$
```

You can make `lsh` add this hostkey to the trusted hostkeys:

```
$ lsh -c aes256-ctr --sloppy-host-authentication --capture-to ~/.lsh/host-acls localhost
Received unauthenticated key for host localhost
Key details:
Bubble Babble: xitem-suten-vedyd-hibuv-naril-nisog-luvet-dagik-negem-kykeb-bexyx
Fingerprint:   4b:9f:4b:4d:10:6b:09:2b:be:ee:df:48:a0:75:d3:9a
Do you trust this key? (y/n) y
Password for tange: 
Last login: Fri Jan  8 12:46:57 2016 from localhost
$
```

And then you can use `lsh` with normal password login:

```
$ lsh -c aes256-ctr localhost
Password for tange: 
Last login: Fri Jan  8 12:48:36 2016 from localhost
$
```

To authorize a client key, convert the key to OpenSSH format and append it to `.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
$ lsh-keygen | lsh-writekey
xxxxxx
xxxxxx
Enter new passphrase: 
Again: 
$ lsh-export-key --openssh < ~/.lsh/identity.pub | lsh -c aes256-ctr localhost 'cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys'
Passphrase for key `tange@hk': 
Password for tange:
```

Now you can use your `lsh` key to connect to an OpenSSH server. To avoid entering passwords do not encrypt your client key:

```
$ lsh-keygen | lsh-writekey -c none
xxxxxx
xxxxxx
$ lsh-export-key --openssh < ~/.lsh/identity.pub | lsh -c aes256-ctr localhost 'cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys'
Password for tange: 
$ lsh -c aes256-ctr localhost
Last login: Fri Jan  8 12:48:40 2016 from localhost
$
```